# How to Create Amazon Lex Response Card in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lex

I've found the Terraform code that creates a response card with the Amazon Lex intent but there doesn't seem to be a way to add the required fields, like image URL or Title to the [response card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlYUl.png). Is it possible to add these fields?

```
Amazon Lex intent resource in Terraform:

resource "aws_lex_intent" "purchase" {
  confirmation_prompt {
    max_attempts = 2

    message {
      content      = "what kind of product would you like?"
      content_type = "PlainText"
    }
  }

  create_version = false
  name           = "Purchase"
  description    = " "

  fulfillment_activity {
    type = "ReturnIntent"
  }

  rejection_statement {
    message {
      content      = "I do not have the information you need."
      content_type = "PlainText"
    }
  }

  sample_utterances = "what products do you have"

  follow_up_prompt{
    prompt {
        message {
          content = "Here is what I found on the site: <a data-gtm-event={chatbot-link} href={firstUrlHref}>{firstUrlTitle}</a> and <a data-gtm-event={chatbot-link} href= {secondUrlHref} >{secondUrlTitle}</a>."
          content_type = "PlainText"
        }
        max_attempts = 2
        response_card = true
    }

    rejection_statement {
      message {
      content      = "I do not have the information you need."
      content_type = "PlainText"
    }
      
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `response_card` is a boolean. I checked here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lex_intent#response_card. There is also a URL pointing to AWS website there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-resp-card.html.

Comment: I also saw that. It would make sense to add a response card as a variable. The question then is how do you create one as a resource? Or you could add it in that field as an object but then what formatting?